# Extract data from pandas dataframe columns with duplicate names

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe which has duplicate column names:

```
Accepted    Accepted    Accepted    Reject    Accepted    Reject
ABC         IJK         JKL         XYJ       LMN         UIO
BCD         PQR         EFG         YVG       GHIJ        PLK
```

...and want to convert it into two dataframes; one only of "Accepted" columns and other for "Reject" Columns:

df1:

```
Accepted    Accepted    Accepted    Accepted
ABC         IJK         JKL         LMN     
BCD         PQR         EFG         GHIJ
```

df2:

```
Reject    Reject
XYJ       UIO
YVG       PLK
```

Tried:

```
df1=df["Accepted"]
df2=df["Reject"]
```

... but this only gives the first column matching this name.

Comment: If you read that dataframe in with `pd.read_csv()`, it will mangle duplicate column names to `Accepted Accepted.1 Accepted.2 Reject Accepted.3 Reject.1`. This is useful behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If select one column with same name are selected all columns with same name in DataFrame:

```
df1 = df['Accepted']
df2 = df['Reject']
```

Then is possible deduplicate columns:

```
df1.columns = [f'{x}_{i}' for i, x in enumerate(df1.columns, 1)]
df2.columns = [f'{x}_{i}' for i, x in enumerate(df2.columns, 1)]
```

EDIT: If get only first column name it means there are not duplicated columns names, so is possible use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Accepted')
df2 = df.filter(like='Reject')
```

Comment: Tried this. It only gives the first column and not all of those.

Comment: @SHLOKDOSHI - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: df.filter worked. But it modifies column names as ```Accepted.2``` , ```Accepted.3``` and so on.

Comment: @SHLOKDOSHI - `filter` modify columns names? What is `print (df.columns.tolist())`  before my solution?

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/71577325/17778275

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this

```
df1 = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(['accepted'])]
```

**OR**

```
df2 = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(['rejected'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to have duplicate column names, but anyway:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.get_loc('Accepted')]

  Accepted Accepted Accepted Accepted
0      ABC      IJK      JKL      LMN
1      BCD      PQR      EFG     GHIJ

df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.get_loc('Reject')]
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO give the same name to columns is not a good practice. use unique names for every column. it doesn't matter if you put a number or add a unique character into the name. just make it unique

Solution from me, rename the column first

```py
df.columns = ['Accepted1','Accepted2','Accepted3','Reject1','Accepted4','Reject2']
df1 = df[['Accepted1','Accepted2','Accepted3','Accepted4']]
df2 = df[['Reject1','Reject2']]
```