# Getting data from different dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame

```
Name    Subset    Type    System
A00     IU00-A    OP      A
A00     IT00      PP      A
B01     IT-01A    PP      B
B01     IU        OP      B
B03     IM-09-B   LP      A
B03     IM03A     OP      A
B03     IT-09     OP      A
D09     IT        OP      A
D09     IM        LP      A
D09     IM        OP      A
```

which I have converted it to

```
Subset Cluster    Type Cluster    Name          System
IU,IT             OP,PP           A00           A
IM,IM,IT          LP, OP, OP      B03, D09      A
IU,IT             OP,PP           B01           B
```

using

```
out = df.assign(Subset=df['Subset'].str[:2])\
        .sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist())\
        .groupby('Name', as_index=False)\
        .agg(**{'Subset Cluster': ('Subset', ', '.join), 
                'Type Cluster': ('Type', ', '.join), 
                'System': ('System', 'first')})\
        .groupby(['Subset Cluster', 'Type Cluster', 'System'], as_index=False)\
        .agg(', '.join)
```

In this converted dataframe, I need to add another column that will give me all subsets for a particular Name.

Output Example:

```
Subset Cluster    Type Cluster    Name          System    Subsets
IU,IT             OP,PP           A00           A         IU00-A,IT00
IM,IM,IT          LP, OP, OP      B03, D09      A         IM-09-B,IM03A,IT-09,IT,IM,IM   
IU,IT             OP,PP           B01           B         IT-01A,IU
```

Comment: How did you get those subsets?

Comment: The sunsets are basically all the subsets of a particular group of Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could assign `Subset Cluster` first; then use a double `groupby`:

```
out = df.assign(**{'Subset Cluster': df['Subset'].str[:2]})\
        .sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist())\
        .groupby(['Name', 'System'], as_index=False)\
        .agg(', '.join).rename(columns={'Type':'Type Cluster'})\
        .groupby(['Subset Cluster', 'Type Cluster', 'System'], as_index=False)\
        .agg(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
  Subset Cluster Type Cluster System      Name                             Subset
0     IM, IM, IT   LP, OP, OP      A  B03, D09  IM-09-B, IM03A, IT-09, IM, IM, IT
1         IT, IU       PP, OP      A       A00                       IT00, IU00-A
2         IT, IU       PP, OP      B       B01                         IT-01A, IU
```

Comment: Kindly note as I need a generic code, where not only first two alphabets are considered for grouping, first alphabetical string as a whole is considered using regex ```extractall(r'[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^,]*').groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)```  
instead of ```df['Subset'].str[:2]```
Here substituting the above regex in my code, i cannot my whole subset string as output. 
Only getting ```IM,IM,IT,IM,IM,IT```

Comment: @spd does it work if you replace `df['Subset'].str[:2]` by `df['Subset'].str.extractall(r'[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^,]*').droplevel(-1)[0]` in the above code?

Comment: No, Cannot get the whole Subset back.

Comment: @spd what do you mean by whole Subset? You're extracting only a part of it, no?

Comment: Extracting only a part of it while grouping, but need whole comma separated subset in the last column.

Comment: @spd ok, but don't you get that with the code I included in my answer? It uses `Subset Cluster` to create groups and aggregate `Subset`

Comment: Unable to get the desired Subset Column

Comment: @spd it works for the toy example though right? Could you include a sample where it breaks?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71795377/17778275 
Please Go through this.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s = """Name    Subset    Type    System
A00     IU00-A    OP      A
A00     IT00      PP      A
B01     IT-01A    PP      B
B01     IU        OP      B
B03     IM-09-B   LP      A
B03     IM03A     OP      A
B03     IT-09     OP      A
D09     IT        OP      A
D09     IM        LP      A
D09     IM        OP      A"""

temp = [x.split() for x in s.split('\n')]
cols = temp[0]
data = temp[1:]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A00', 'B03, D09', 'B01']})

vals = []
for val in df1['Name']:
    t = val.replace(', ', '|')
    vals.append(df[df['Name'].str.contains(t)]['Subset'].values)
    
df1['Subsets']=vals
```

Output:

[image]