# Data Grouping with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame

```
Name    Subset    Type    System
A00     IU00-A    OP      A
A00     IT00      PP      A
B01     IT-01A    PP      B
B01     IU        OP      B
B03     IM-09-B   LP      A
B03     IM03A     OP      A
B03     IT-09     OP      A
D09     IT        OP      A
D09     IM        LP      B
D09     IM        OP      A
```

The abouve dataframe, I need to convert it based on Grouping Name and Subset strings extracted using `extractall(r'[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^,]*').groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)`. And Systems, Subsets Should be mentioned serially according to Types.

Output Example:

```
Subset Cluster    Type Cluster    Name          System        Subsets
IU,IT             OP,PP           A00,B01       A,A,B,B       IU00-A,IT00
IM,IM,IT          LP, OP, OP      B03, D09      A,A,A,A,B,A   IM-09-B,IM03A,IT-09,IT,IM,IM
```

Comment: How are created groups? Your code `extractall(r'[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^,]*')` return error, maybe someting missing?

Comment: The code snippet is used for extraction of "Subset". Groups are not created. I need to create groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double `groupby` where we first group by "Name", then again by "Subset Cluster" and "Type Cluster" does the trick:

```
out = df.assign(**{'Subset Cluster': df['Subset'].str.extractall(r'[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^,]*')\
                                                 .groupby(level=0)[0].agg(', '.join)})\
        .sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist())\
        .groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(', '.join).rename(columns={'Type':'Type Cluster'})\
        .groupby(['Subset Cluster', 'Type Cluster'], as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
  Subset Cluster  Type Cluster      Name                             Subset            System
0     IM, IM, IT    LP, OP, OP  B03, D09  IM-09-B, IM03A, IT-09, IM, IM, IT  A, A, A, B, A, A  
1         IT, IU        PP, OP  A00, B01           IT00, IU00-A, IT-01A, IU        A, A, B, B
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning from your dataframe, in order to achieve your result I would use two aggregating operations since you need to do two groupings, relatively to `Name` and `Subset Cluster`. Here's the way I would do it:

```
df.rename(columns={'Subset': 'Subset Cluster'}, inplace=True)
df['Subsets'] = df['Subset Cluster'].apply(lambda s: s[:2])

df = df.groupby('Name').agg(lambda col: ', '.join(sorted(list(col))) ).reset_index()
df = df.groupby('Subsets').agg(lambda col: ', '.join(sorted(list(col))) ).reset_index()

df
```

Comment: For slicing the subset instead of ```s[:2]``` I have to use ```(r'[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^,]*') ``` as I need to extract first alphabetical string, it is not compulsorily first two characters.
Can you please modify the code.